# Can't cast ECPublicKeyImpl to DSAPublicKey

Tags: java, cryptography

I would like to use DSAPublicKey but I have casting problem. Do I need some external libraries?

Code:

```
byte[] encoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(publicKey);
KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC");
DSAPublicKey pubKey = (DSAPublicKey) kf.generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(encoded));
BigInteger x = pubKey.getY();
```

But I am getting this strange error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class sun.security.ec.ECPublicKeyImpl cannot be cast to class java.security.interfaces.DSAPublicKey 
(sun.security.ec.ECPublicKeyImpl is in module jdk.crypto.ec of loader 'platform'; java.security.interfaces.DSAPublicKey is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at se.digg.dgc.signatures.impl.DefaultDGCSigner.sign(DefaultDGCSigner.java:232)
    at se.digg.dgc.interop.CreateTestDataTest.createTestStatement(CreateTestDataTest.java:247)
    at se.digg.dgc.interop.CreateTestDataTest.test1_vacEntry(CreateTestDataTest.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
```

is there another lib needed?

Comment: For DSA, not `EC` must be applied when instantiating the `KeyFactory`, but `DSA`, see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/security/KeyFactory.html). Or is it about ECDSA? Then `ECPublicKey` would have to be used instead of `DSAPublicKey`.

Comment: Thank you for help